# I have music playing and when i flip my screen up the music shuts down

Tags: windows, laptop, spotify

My music (I use spotify) turns off everytime i put my computer(windows laptop) to sleep. On my desktop i don't have this problem.

Comment: Because you're not really putting the desktop to sleep, just locking the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you shut the screen/lid of your laptop it logs you out of windows/puts it to sleep and thereby doesn’t allow you to continue your music.

What you could do in order to continue listening to your music while still shutting the screen/lid of your laptop is to turn off the “go to sleep” function when the screen/lid is closed/shut on your laptop which can be done as follows:-

1. Go to control panel.
2. Select “Hardware and sound”.
3. Select “Power options”.
4. Select “Change when the computer sleeps”.
5. Select “Change advanced power settings”.
6. Select “Power buttons and lid”(Click the plus sign to open the sub-menu).
7. Click the plus sign of the “Lid close action”.
8. And change the settings from “Sleep” to “Do nothing” in both “On battery” and “Plugged in” section.

**Note, doing this will allow you to play your music when the lid is closed but it won’t *log you out of windows/put it to sleep* when you shut the lid.**

P.S. This is what I do to listen to music on spotify with the lid of my laptop closed.

When you connect your laptop to an external display which in this case is your desktop,your laptop is supposed to still function properly as it thinks that it is projecting something.
Also,if your question meant that when you put your PC to sleep it still plays your music then I am afraid I can help you with that but I hope I gave you a good suggestion to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is an almost new option called modern standby. that is exactly like sleep in smartphones. Apps steel working and internet connection is on, but everything is on power saving mode.
And that's why sometimes fans spin in sleep mode.
I have to notice that this option required hardware and software compatibility and old Hardwares don't support it.
i hope that helps you know about your saturation.